# If "-f %{REQUEST_FILENAME}" what mean's - fcgi

Tags: centos, fastcgi

I configures my apache + php-fpm + mod_proxy_fcgi server and I can't understand the line in the two tutorials that don't explain why. This is not found in any other tutorial.

```
<FilesMatch "\.php$">
<If "-f %{REQUEST_FILENAME} && %{REQUEST_URI} =~ /.+\.ph(ar|p|tml)$/" >

SetHandler "proxy:unix:/run/php-fpm/example.com.sock|fcgi://example.com/"

</if>
</FilesMatch>
```

---

I don't understand line:

```
<If "-f %{REQUEST_FILENAME} && %{REQUEST_URI} =~ /.+\.ph(ar|p|tml)$/" >
```

I was able to determine that this line means:
'check if the file really exists' I understand correctly? If so, why check? maybe it's not needed?

Comment: I fixed formating issue. (code is to be formated using `{}` button) (thanks for deleting your answer)

Comment: sorry i'm new here

Comment: that's OK formatting can be tricky. Important thing it that piece of code can be show.

Comment: by the way I read the code as file exists **and** URI ends in (.php or .phar or .phtml)

Comment: okey, but when I delete this line, nothing changes. No file  - causes the same error, and an empty file - displays a blank page.

Do changes occur in processes?

Comment: Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0):

With that line, you only delegate to php-fpm those requests that are actually calling a PHP file.
That way you avoid calling php-fpm unnecessarily for files that are not relevant to php-fpm because they are not PHP.